# Android Gson Json parse when key number is undefined

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have the following Json response

```
{
  "time": {
        "1427817600000": 90,
        "1427904000000": 134,
        "1427990400000": 155,
        "1428076800000": 167
  }
}
```

And the number of items in "time" is undefined.

For example,

at the time "1427817600000", the count is 90

at the time "1427904000000", the count is 134
...
...

How can I parse this in Android (Java)

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you can use a JsonArray http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: But it seems that it's JSONObject for "time"

Comment: It depends on whether or not the keys are known. From what you've posted, it seems like the key is a random time value. While you might be able to run through the list of key/value pairs and do whatever it is you're trying to do, using Gson wouldn't be possible here because Gson needs to know the key names at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate each and every key of `"time"` JSON by using `org.json` library

E.g.

```
String data = "{\"time\": {\"1427817600000\": 90,\"1427904000000\": 134,\"1427990400000\": 155,\"1428076800000\": 167}}";

JSONObject json=new JSONObject(data);   
JSONObject timeJSON=json.getJSONObject("time");

Iterator<String> keys=timeJSON.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()){
 System.out.println(timeJSON.get(keys.next()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys by calling JSONObject's keys() method.

Answer (score 0):

Store your JSON string in variable say `resultStr`

Code :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(resultStr);

JSONObject timeObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("time");

int count1 = timeObject.getString("1427817600000");

int count2 = timeObject.getString("1427904000000");

int count3 = timeObject.getString("1427990400000");

int count4 = timeObject.getString("1428076800000");
```